# Swing Application Framework @Action annotation ? what for?

Tags: java, swing

I'm actually using the Swing Application Framework on a desktop application and make good use of the session state persistence and resource manager (great for globalization)

Now I have been testing the @Action annotation feature, and really I don't see any advantage over NOT using it.
The official doc lists mainly these advantages:

> you can conveniently put all the
>   relevant visual cues and the
>   event-processing logic for a component
>   in one place.

Yes this place storing the visual cues is the resource bundle. (can be used with Resource Manager)
Yes the event-processing logic in one place is within a common method. but no need to annotate a method in order to make it common to several events.

> Another convenient benefit of using
>   Action interfaces is that you can
>   reuse the same action across multiple
>   UI components. GUIs often provide
>   multiple ways to accomplish a task

Yes, obviously event-processing can be common to different events, but again using the @Action annotation isn't required to call a common method from different action listeners methods.

I don't see much of an advantage writing this :

```
 openButton.setAction(actionMap.get("open"));
 // NOI18N

 @Action public void open() {
     // processing logic 
 }
```

instead of:

```
 openButton.addActionListener(new
 java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                 openButtonActionPerformed(evt);
             } });

 private void openButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     // processing logic 
 }
```

To mention that using the latter, I keep my method private, which is neater, and I also keep control over specific components getting added the listener (as each of them will have their own resources, instead of sharing the same visual cue!)

Anyone found an real interest in using @Action annotations ?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation provides the answer to your question.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/Action.html

I think the advantage to using @Action rather than the anonymous ActionListener is that @Action is a very nice and convenient hook into the framework which makes it really easy to localize things for the action such as icons, text, or mnemonics. Additionally, if your @Action annotated method returns a Task object, the framework appropriately handles executing code that should not run on the EDT.

Without using the frameworks @Action you'd have to be very careful to localize your ActionListeners and be even more careful about how you manage code that should not run on the EDT (if you want a responsive UI).

Using @Action on a method that returns a Task is a very powerful convenience this framework provides.

Answer (score 1):

When I use NetBeans every method marked with @Action will be automatically available in the NetBeans GUI for setting actions on components.

Comment: I get that. But why would you use annotations in order to set actions to components in the netbeans editor instead of (still using NetBeans editor) adding event listener to components ? what's the advantage?

Comment: Well aren't they there so that some things can be done automatically for you and save you some boiler plate code? I have not used it for a while now so I cannot really remember what the framework+netbeans did for you

Comment: I don't see what code is generated automatically using annotation that cannot be also generated automatically by NetBeans editor.
Really I don't see any advantage in the use of action annotations.